# Finding Sub-String in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I'm trying to do a check to see if there are any sub-strings in a `UITextView`. Currently, this is how I go about doing that:

```
if ([self.textView.text rangeOfString:@"string"].location == NSNotFound) 
{
    NSLog(@"self.textView.text contains string");
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run this code I don't get a response, indicating that the test failed, as there is in fact the word: **string** used in the `UITextView`. How would I go about checking if there are any sub-strings in a `UITextView`?

Comment: This statement is true when text is *not* found. You probably want `!=` instead of `==`.

Comment: @FilipRadelic Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `!=` to `==`! The `if` statement is telling you that the instance of string **not** found. Use this statement instead:

```
if ([self.textView.text rangeOfString:@"string"].location != NSNotFound) 
{
    NSLog(@"self.textView.text contains string");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing you can implement like this below as well. If you do not want to change the equal operator condition:-

```
 if (![self.textView.text rangeOfString:@"string"].location == NSNotFound) 
{
    NSLog(@"self.textView.text contains string");
}
```